# MVC5 - Dynamically choose which properties are displayed in an form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, dynamic

Let's say I have two users who are accessing a form.  One is an admin user and one is a normal user.  And only the admin can view and edit `AdminOnlyField`   Then let's say I have the following class:

```
public class Car
{
    public string Make {get;set;}
    public string Model {get;set;}
    public string AdminOnlyField {get;set;}

}
```

I'm not able to figure out how to conditionally make the `AdminOnlyField` visible and editable using `@html.BeginForm()`,  I know you can use properties from `ViewBag` but in this case all the information I need is coming back from a database so I don't think I can utilize `ViewBag`.

Is this something MVC can accomplish or do I need to explore Angular?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to insert `if(User.IsInRole(stringRole))`

Yet if you want to hide this mechanism you can make an EditorTemplate.

The file has to be in location `Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/EditFormTemplate.cshtml`

For AdminOnlyField you can hide this functionality by template.

```
@if(User.IsInRole("Admin")
{
    <div>
        <label>AdminOnlyField: </label>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => Model.AdminOnlyField)
    </div>
}
```

Usage:

```
@Html.EditorForModel("YourCustomTemplateName")
```

If you need more information:

[There is more information](https://exceptionnotfound.net/asp-net-mvc-demystified-display-and-editor-templates/)

Comment: Okay, interesting answer, but on a larger concept, what if the the if statement can only come back from information I have in the database?  For example AdminOnlyField.visble = true

Comment: Would this need a custom attribute and then populated preload?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean.
If you store some boolean value in database which represents the field visibility of model, you can combine it. Probably, you use EF and lazy loading, so for model you can use eager loading to minimize number of database requests. Could you clarify your situation?

Comment: I think you're over complicating it.  For user 1, I might load 12 properties of out 30 and for users 2 i might load 8 of 30.  There is a possible 30 properties in the model.  How do you display a dynamic model.  Forget user roles, or anything.   My database table has 30 columns, user 1 sees a set of 12 properties users 2 has a set of properties.  It's all dynamic so you  therefore cannot statically establish the Razor View...

Comment: Okay this might clarify the question, if you're using entity framework, would you construct the view in such where the model will dynamically change?

Comment: I got your point. So, I think, in this case you had better use angular, and if the model changes dynamically then try to see what [CQRS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt790196.aspx) is. If you have time. This supporting architecture fits well with dynamically changing data, but the implementation is quite complicated. In any case, the razor renders the view and gives it, no more. It is static view. I hope it helps you.